# Simultaneous update, delete and add a list item to a sharepoint List object

Tags: development, client-object-model

In the MSDN documentation for C# CSOM, there are separate examples for  adding, updating or deleting a single list item from a sharepoint list object (ListItemCollection)

Is it possible to combine all the above operations in a loop and then call the executeQuery method?

for example:

```
//create the list item collection object

List oList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(Helper.helper.ListName);
            CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
            ListItemCollection items = oList.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(items);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

//iterate through the list item collection, process each item and accordingly add,update or delete:

foreach (ListItem lItem in items)
{
  if(/*some condition*/)
  {
  lItem.deleteObject;

  }

  if(/*some condition*/)
  {
   lItem["Title"]="Some Title";
   lItem.Update();
   }

   if(/* some condition */)
   {
     // code for creating newItemCreationInfo and then add the list item
    }

  }

 context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Short and sweet: Will the above logic work???

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Short and sweet: TRY IT :)

Comment: Works like a charm.. really short and  sweet ;)